# cython np.import_array() fails due to mismatched API versions

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Anyone have any idea why I get this error:

```
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  method tm_excepthook in test.py at line 44
   io = fdopen(error_fd, 'wb', 0)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  method <module> in test.py at line 9
    import SLIC
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

RuntimeError: 'module compiled against API version 6 but this version of numpy is 4'
```

I have tried reinstalling numpy with no luck (1.6.2 built from source on OSX Lion), oddly enough though, when I type `numpy.__version__` i get 1.5.1, and in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/version.py tells me I am using 1.6.2

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might have multiple version of numpy, check which one is actually being loaded by running

```
import numpy
print(numpy.__file__)
```

Now, check your Python include paths by doing

```
import os
print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])
```

The place of your incorrect numpy should be higher up in the list. Try to correct this by changing your `PYTHONPATH`.